# Font style: Stretched then thin, liquid-like appearance

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Sorry, I'm not sure how to describe this trend but it's something I've seen a lot of in 2019.

The font is distorted in a way that some parts are stretched and thick, and some parts are compressed and thin.

Like this book cover but thicker

[image]

What's the name for this style?

Comment: maybe not font at all but just streched shapes! :) but internet is so vast so maybe it can be font too

Comment: If this is a style or trend, then it is best avoided in my opinion.  It looks awful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a name for these distortions as a simple style, I will adopt two: **dynamic typeface** and **responsive font**.

## Dynamic Typeface

I took this name from the [Francis Gradient](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/francis_gradient/about) font description because I think it is very illustrative of this feature:

> Francis’ real tour de force, however is its collection of four Gradient styles, capital-only display versions that **produce dynamically increasing or decreasing character widths**. These remarkable text patterns are possible because each Gradient style contains 2,690 glyphs that are selected automatically using OpenType’s Contextual Alternates feature.

[image]

[image]

---

## Responsive Font

The terminology used in web design applied to several devices is influencing all the elements used in its creation, also the design. The only possibility of making a text or font responsive is by modifying its length or typographic variable like size or weight. There's still no change in the design itself, but it's a very good idea to implement: a responsive font design.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I was asking if there is a standard name for the effect that you've provided - from the responses it looks unlikely. But thank you for providing the examples - they provide further context in my search.

Comment: It's not a comment, is an answer to your question: *I'm not sure if there's a name for these distortions as a simple style*.

Comment: There are variable fonts already, although responsive in a different way https://v-fonts.com/

Answer (score 0):

I gave to it just name "Node shifting" due the easy method how to make it.

At first outline the text and ungroup the result. Select the letters which need to be stretched or moved, here D and E. Then select the nodes to be moved:

[image]

Move the selected nodes:

[image]

I'm not at all sure does somewhere exist a more respected person who uses different name.